# why tableview cell is not displaying for the first time in iOS 15?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have made my app completely Programatic UI. With iOS 15 I am having a weird issue however with previous iOS versions its working fine as expected. So I have couple of buttons on top of the view, while clicking each button the below table view will be reloaded. When I click on one particular button the table view cell is not showing  anything but the space is occupied. At the same time if I press any other button and comeback to the same button everything looks perfect. Kindly check the below code and  shed some light.

> ModeOfPaymentTableViewCell

```
class ModeOfPaymentTableViewCell: UITableViewCell{

class var identifier: String { return String.className(self) }

let addressDescriptionTextView:UILabel = {
    let textView = UILabel()
    textView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    textView.textAlignment = .natural
    textView.textColor = .gray
    textView.font = K.FONT.FONT17
    textView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    textView.numberOfLines = 0
    return textView
}()

let otherLabel:UILabel = {
    let lbl = UILabel()
    lbl.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    lbl.textColor = UIColor.black
    lbl.textAlignment = .natural
    lbl.font = K.FONT.FONT17
    return lbl
}()

let indicatorImage:UIImageView = {
    let imageview = UIImageView()
    imageview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints =  false
    imageview.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Back")
    return imageview
}()

let cardImage : UIImageView = {
    let imageview = UIImageView()
    imageview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints =  false
    imageview.contentMode = UIView.ContentMode.scaleAspectFit
    return imageview
}()

var primaryData = [String](){
    didSet{
        setUpDescriptionTextView()
    }
}

let shimmer = ShimmerCellWithOutImage()

var showShimmer = Bool(){
    didSet{
        shimmer.isHidden = !showShimmer
    }
}

override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    
    shimmer.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    self.addSubview(shimmer)
    self.addSubview(addressDescriptionTextView)
    self.addSubview(otherLabel)
    self.addSubview(cardImage)
    self.addSubview(indicatorImage)
    
    self.borderColor = UIColor.groupTableViewBackground
    self.borderWidth = 1
    
    self.backgroundColor = .white
    
    self.selectionStyle = .none
    
    setUpUI()
    
    if Language.type == "en" || Language.type == "en-SA"{
        otherLabel.textAlignment = .right
        indicatorImage.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Next")
    }
    else if Language.type == "ar" || Language.type == "ar-SA" {
        otherLabel.textAlignment = .left
        indicatorImage.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Back")
    }
    else{
        otherLabel.textAlignment = .right
        indicatorImage.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Next")
    }
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("failed to load the frame")
}

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

override public func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    shimmer.shimmerView.addShimmerAnimation()
}


func setUpDescriptionTextView(){
    
    let leftSideValue = primaryData[0].components(separatedBy: ",")
    
    let attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString()
    
    attributedText.append(NSAttributedString(
                            string: "\n" + leftSideValue[0], attributes: 
    [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : 
  
  
 UIColor(hex:K.COLOR.GRAYTEXTCOLOR),NSAttributedString.Key.font:K.FONT.BOLDFONT12!]))

    attributedText.append(NSAttributedString(
                            string: "\n" + "\(leftSideValue[1])" + "\n", attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : UIColor.black,NSAttributedString.Key.font:K.FONT.FONT17!]))
    
    addressDescriptionTextView.attributedText =  attributedText
    if primaryData[1] != " 0.0 " && primaryData[1] != ""{
        //            otherLabel.set(image: UIImage.directionIndicator()!, with: primaryData[1])
        let data = primaryData[1];
        if data == "VISA" || data == "MADA" || data == "MASTER"{
            if data == "VISA" {
                cardImage.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "visa")
            }else if data == "MADA"{
                cardImage.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "mada")
            }else if data == "MASTER"{
                cardImage.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "mascard")
            }else{
                cardImage.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "CARDS")
            }
            otherLabel.isHidden = true
            cardImage.isHidden = false
        }else{
            otherLabel.text = data
            otherLabel.isHidden = false
            cardImage.isHidden = true

        }
        
        otherLabel.tintColor = UIColor(hex:K.COLOR.BLUE)
    }else{
   
    
    }
    
    
}



override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    
    // Configure the view for the selected state
}



func setUpUI() {
    
    [shimmer.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor,constant: 2),
     shimmer.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo:leadingAnchor, constant: 0),
     shimmer.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: 0),
     shimmer.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor,constant:-2)].forEach{$0.isActive =  true}

    [addressDescriptionTextView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor,constant: 0),
     addressDescriptionTextView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo:leadingAnchor, constant: 10),
     addressDescriptionTextView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor, constant: -UIScreen.main.bounds.width/2),
     addressDescriptionTextView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor,constant:0)].forEach{$0.isActive =  true}


    [otherLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor,constant: 0),
     otherLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: addressDescriptionTextView.trailingAnchor, constant: 2),
     otherLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -25),
     otherLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor,constant:0)].forEach{$0.isActive =  true}

    [cardImage.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor,constant: 0),
//         cardImage.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: addressDescriptionTextView.trailingAnchor, constant: 2),
     cardImage.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -25),
     cardImage.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor,constant:0)].forEach{$0.isActive =  true}


    [indicatorImage.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor),
     indicatorImage.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -10),
     indicatorImage.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 15),
     indicatorImage.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 10)].forEach{$0.isActive =  true}
    
}

}


EwalletDetailsViewController
```

Here the issue happens under case Reload:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    
    
    tableView.separatorStyle = .none
    
    switch selectedType {
        
    case "Activity":
        let cell:generalActivityTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(
            withIdentifier: generalActivityTableViewCell.identifier,
            for: indexPath) as! generalActivityTableViewCell
        
        let date = convertDateStringToFormatedDateString(date: self.activityData?.data?[indexPath.row].date_time ?? "")

        cell.activityDescriptionDetails =  "\(self.activityData?.data?[indexPath.row].title ?? "") & \(self.activityData?.data?[indexPath.row].desc ?? "")"
        cell.activityValueDetails = "\(date) & \(self.activityData?.data?[indexPath.row].amount ?? "")"
        return cell
        
    case "Transfer":
    
        if indexPath.row == 1{
            
            if selectedEwalletForTransfer?.ewallet_number ?? "" == ""{
                
                let cell:OtherAccountViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(
                    withIdentifier: OtherAccountViewCell.identifier,
                    for: indexPath) as! OtherAccountViewCell
        
                return cell
                
            }else{
                
                let cell:ModeOfPaymentTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(
                    withIdentifier: ModeOfPaymentTableViewCell.identifier,
                    for: indexPath) as! ModeOfPaymentTableViewCell
                cell.selectionStyle = .none
                cell.showShimmer  = false
                cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
                if selectedEwalletForTransfer?.ewallet_title == ""{
                    cell.primaryData = ["\("To Ewallet Account".localized())"+","+"\(selectedEwalletForTransfer?.ewallet_number ?? "")", "\(selectedEwalletForTransfer?.currency_label ?? "") "+"\(selectedEwalletForTransfer?.balance ?? "") " ]
                }else{
                    cell.primaryData = ["\("To Ewallet Account".localized())"+","+"\(selectedEwalletForTransfer?.ewallet_number ?? "") "+"-"+" \(selectedEwalletForTransfer?.ewallet_title ?? "")" , "\(selectedEwalletForTransfer?.currency_label ?? "") "+"\(selectedEwalletForTransfer?.balance ?? "") " ]
                }
                return cell
            }
            
        }else{
            let cell:ReloadPickerCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(
                withIdentifier: ReloadPickerCell.identifier,
                for: indexPath) as! ReloadPickerCell
            cell.currencyPicker.delegate = self
            cell.currencyPicker.dataSource = self
            cell.amountPicker.delegate = self
            cell.amountPicker.dataSource = self
            cell.amountLabel.isHidden = false
            cell.amountLabel.delegate = self
            cell.selecteTitleLabel.text = "Enter Amount to transfer".localized()

            return cell
        }
        
       
    case "Reload":
        if indexPath.row == 1{
            let cell:ModeOfPaymentTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(
                withIdentifier: ModeOfPaymentTableViewCell.identifier,
                for: indexPath) as! ModeOfPaymentTableViewCell
            cell.selectionStyle = .none
            cell.showShimmer = false
            if self.selectedCard != nil{
             cell.primaryData = ["\("CARD INFO".localized())"+","+"\(self.selectedCard?.card_masked_number ?? "")", "\(self.selectedCard?.card_brand ?? "")" ]
            }else{
                cell.primaryData = ["\("CARD INFO".localized())"+","+"Click here to add your credit card".localized(), "" ]
            }
            cell.layoutSubviews()
            return cell
        }else{
            let cell:ReloadPickerCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(
                withIdentifier: ReloadPickerCell.identifier,
                for: indexPath) as! ReloadPickerCell
            cell.currencyPicker.delegate = self
            cell.currencyPicker.dataSource = self
            cell.amountPicker.delegate = self
            cell.amountPicker.dataSource = self
            cell.amountLabel.isHidden = true
            cell.selecteTitleLabel.text = "ENTER AMOUNT TO RELOAD".localized()
            return cell
        }
        
    case "Share":
        let cell:SharedTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(
            withIdentifier: SharedTableViewCell.identifier,
            for: indexPath) as! SharedTableViewCell
        cell.showShimmer = false
        
        
        let date = convertDateStringToFormatedDateString(date: self.shareData?.data?[indexPath.row].shared_date ?? "")
        
        cell.primaryData =   ["\(self.shareData?.data?[indexPath.row].shared_email ?? "")" + "," + "\(self.shareData?.data?[indexPath.row].user_name ?? "")","\(date)","\(self.shareData?.data?[indexPath.row].profile_pic ?? "")"]
        
        return cell
        
    default:
        return UITableViewCell()
    }
}

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    switch selectedType {
    case "Activity":
        return UITableView.automaticDimension
    case "Transfer":
        if indexPath.row == 1{
            if selectedEwalletForTransfer?.ewallet_number ?? "" == ""{
                return 120
            }else{
                return UITableView.automaticDimension
            }
        }else{
            return 110
        }
    case "Reload":
        if indexPath.row == 1{
            if self.cardData?.data?.count == 0{
                return UITableView.automaticDimension
            }else{
                return UITableView.automaticDimension
            }
        }else{
            return 110
        }
    case "Share":
        return UITableView.automaticDimension
    default:
        return 0
    }
    
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    switch selectedType {
    case "Activity":
        return UITableView.automaticDimension
    case "Transfer":
        if indexPath.row == 1{
            if selectedEwalletForTransfer?.ewallet_number ?? "" == ""{
                return 120
            }else{
                return UITableView.automaticDimension
            }
        }else{
            return 110
        }
    case "Reload":
        if indexPath.row == 1{
            if self.cardData?.data?.count == 0 || self.cardData?.data == nil && OPPPaymentProvider.deviceSupportsApplePay() && self.selectedEwallet?.currency_code == "SAR" {
                return UITableView.automaticDimension
            }else{
                return UITableView.automaticDimension
            }
        }else{
            return 110
        }
    case "Share":
        return UITableView.automaticDimension
    default:
        return 0
    }
    
}
```

Comment: comment all your code without setupViews and add background color to your cell and tableView

Comment: I have tried that already however the behavior is the same.  When I press the button tableview reload with empty space but next time when  I press I am able to see the background color.

Comment: First, you should add all of your UI elements to the cell's `contentView`, not to the cell itself. They should also be constrained to the `contentView`. Not sure if that has anything to do with your issue though... your code has ***a lot*** of stuff that we don't know - such as what is `ShimmerCellWithOutImage`? If changing the view hierarchy to use the `contentView` doesn't fix the problem, try to re-post your code so that we can copy/paste/run it.